# can't attach .mdf into sql server management

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Why can't I browse deeper into the folder, I still have some folders there:
[alt text http://img168.imageshack.us/img168/3056/mdf.jpg](http://img168.imageshack.us/img168/3056/mdf.jpg)

Comment: While this may be a stupid question, but the file exists *on the server* in that location, not *on your machine*, right?

Comment: Yes, when you try to attach a mdf file, the folders you are browsing are those of the computer where the SQL Server is installed, not on your computer.

Comment: This might be a stupid answer too, however the server is my computer...

Comment: SQL Server is installed in my computer.... EQUINOX is the name of the computer

Comment: Not a stupid answer at all ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your SQL Server service account likely does not have access to the folder you're attempting to browse. The ideal solution (from a security perspective) would be to move the file to another, non user-specific location. However, what you're trying to do can be done.

1. Determine the SQL Server instance service account. To do this, view your computer's services and locate "SQL Server" or "SQL Server (instancename)". Double-click and select the "Log On" tab to determine the account being used.
2. Starting with the user's folder, alter the security to grant read and browse permission to the user located in step 1. You'll need to do this for each folder in the path, starting with the the user (in other words, if it's in `C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop`, you'll have to do this on `user` and `Desktop`).
3. Locate the specific file you wish to attach and grant read and write privileges to the same account.

To alter the permissions on a folder or file, right-click and select "Properties", then the "Security" tab. You can add additional permissions by clicking "Add..." and locating the user that you want to explicitly grant (allow) or deny permissions to.

Comment: an answer posted 1 year ago, can still get someone out of frustration.. thanks a lot! By the way I have spent hours searching the web before I came accross to this post!!

Answer (score 6):

I had a mdf file on my desktop but couldn't access it either due to not being able to browse deeper.

I solved it by going to

start > all programs > Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 > Sql Server Configuration Manager

within the Sql configuration manager I went to SQL Server Services and double clicked on the instance running > Log On > change built-in account to 'Local System'. Mine was set to network services but as soon as a changed it to local system I could access my desktop and all my user files.

Answer (score 1):

The subfolders in **users** are often password-protected and can only be accessed by the owner of the user folder. If the folder you are trying to access *is* your own, then you may have a permissions problem and need to modify the folder settings in your OS.

Try navigating to the folder outside of SQL Manager, in Windows Explorer. If you still can't access the folder you may need to try logging on an administrator-level user and modify the folder permissions.

Comment: It's unlikely that the user's current credentials have anything at all to do with the permissions at play here. The permissions of the appropriate instance service account would be what determines whether or not the file could be accessed by the server.

Comment: I definitely can access the folder outside of SQL Manager... How do I modify the permissions problem?

Comment: If you can access the folder outside of SQL Manager, then you have me stumped, because the application should have the same read/write permissions as your login. I was expecting the folder to prohibit access no matter how you tried to navigate to it, except logging in as a different account.